# How to write code in xslfo for the following output?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have a list of records like
One
two
three
When i am using `<fo:list-item></fo:list-item>` iam getting output as

```
[1]. One
[2]. Two
[3]. Three
```

Here we need to remove "." from that list of items. Can anyone help with this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified Sample from the [W3C xsl-fo spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#d0e12374)

```
  <fo:list-item>
    <fo:list-item-label start-indent="5mm" end-indent="label-end()">
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:number format="1"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:list-item-label>
    <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:list-item-body>
  </fo:list-item>
```

Specify the format you want inside the `xsl:number format=` like e.g.  `1` to get numbers without dots.